# How to fix Push Failed unexpected HTTP status code: 500 GitKraken

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket, gitkraken

When I change the code and push it through GitKraken to the repo to BitBucket I got this error:

> Push failed unexpected HTTP status code: 500

[image: B]GitGrakenerror[1]]

Comment: Is pushing working from the command line?

Comment: Yes, pushing is working from the command line. I tried SmartGit and it is working fine. facing the issue with GitKraken Only.

Comment: Are you using just a password, or an ssh key as well?

Comment: Just the password

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We seem to be having the same issue. One of our developers said it started doing this around 11/2018. It was working fine for them before that.

Comment: No, I.ve tried every possible solution but didn't work for me. so I moved to SmartGit, it is working smoothly without any issue. Yes issue started around 11/2018

Comment: We also have this issue, but it didn't start until more recently... we had a drive failure in the git server and so had to rebuild it, and the issue started after the rebuild. No idea what changed on the git server though.

Comment: I've now also got the same issue. git push from command line not a problem pushing to a local BitBucket server, but always get a 500 when pushing from GitKraken

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue - git push from command line works, but any pushes from gitkraken resulted in a 500 error.
We use a BitBucket server, and authentication has always been with username/passwords that match our Windows domain logon credentials.
Whilst trying to investigate I tried using SSH authentication and BitBucket Personal Access Tokens, but neither made any difference.

I've found that I don't get an issue if I push ONE change at a time, and only see the issue when multiple commits are being pushed. I had thought I had solved the problem by clearing out my cache and re-entering details but this only appeared to work because I tested my changes by pushing one more change from local to origin.
So, I haven't got a fix, only a workaround - push after any local commit.